# Conditional free shipping: if subtotal >= X and category != Y

Tags: magento-1.9, free-shipping

I am trying to set conditional free shipping in our store.

We are on CE1.9.1.

WHAT I EXPECT:

1. If subtotal is over $80, and there are no items from Category 44 or 45 in the basket, shipping is free.
2. If subtotal is under $80, and there are no items from Category 44 or 45 in the basket, shipping is uses Aus Post (Fontis Australia extension).
3. If there are items from category 44 or 45 in the basket, shipping is not free at all.

Category 44 is Hats, Cat 45 is Akubra which is a sub category of Hats.

Here's how it looks:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Anyway, I cannot get this to trigger.

We are using Fontis Australia's extension for Aus Post shipping.
Table/flat rates are turned off.
Free shipping (Mage native) is on, with an $80 threshold.

I would appreciate any advice in getting this working!

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Is one of**" condition is broken in 1.9.1

Under your not found condition change to:

**category is 44**

*and under that*

**category is 45.**

Separate them and the rule should work.

**Solutions for part 1 and 3.**

You should turn on magento free shipping and set your minimum high, like 10000 at the shipping method config.  That will keep your free shipping deactivated in general until a shopping cart rule tells it otherwise.  I believe this is ONE of your problems. If you have 80 set there, it doesn't care about your rule, because the minimum 80 is already met.

** OVERALL SOLUTION ***

SOLVED.

My target category was a sub cat. i.e. Akubra (cat 44) was a sub-cat of Hats (cat 45).

I simply set it up like this.

Mage native Free shipping: threshold 10000 Rule: Conditions

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
 Subtotal  equals or greater than  80  
 If an item is NOT FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
  Category  is  44
```

Actions

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
  Category  is not  44
```

Apply to shipping amount: no 
Free shipping: for shipment with matching items 
Stop further rules processing: no

Now:
a) if shipment is over $80, with no Akubra hats, shipping free
b) if shipping is under $80, use Aus Post (via API) 
c) if Akubra in basket, use Aus Post, regardless of sub total

Comment: Hey Ladle, thanks, but still no joy.

Comment: What happens if you deactivate the rule altogether.  Is your shipping charging as intended?

Comment: Also try change condition to if an item IS FOUND with ALL of these conditions true.  Category is not 44 and Category is not 45

Comment: Also, I might be mistaken, but I think you need the magento free shipping for this.  I'm pretty sure that's exactly what the cart rules use.   Also you need to set your conditions the same for the only apply to cart items section.

Comment: Hey Ladle (thanks for your help, I appreciate it) -- if disabled, makes no difference. I also made those other two changes, to no effect. I have Fontis' Australia extension, so am using Australia Post. Also, I have table rates activated. In either case: Aus Post values don't go to zero, and, table rates are stuck on 0. Tim

Comment: 1.  What full magento version you on?   2.  Name exactly the desired results.  Examples of what you expect table rates to do etc.  To me this doesn't currently look like a rule issue.  Try making a product discount with your rule and see if that works to test your conditions are set properly.

Comment: Ok @ladle3000, it looks like this now, with free shipping re-enabled, we have [image1] (http://i.imgur.com/fIJJsUs.png) and [image2] (http://i.imgur.com/t9BciT3.png), I think the condition of $80 or more is redundant, as free shipping's threshold is $80. --- just tested, definitely not picking up the hat in the basket and honouring the limits.

Comment: Your rules look good.  Please answer my previous 2 questions so I can help further.

Comment: FYI you should set apply discount to shipping to No, since your percent discount is zero anyway.

Comment: Ladle, have updated original question to cover your q's.

Comment: You should turn on magento free shipping and set your minimum high, like 10000 at the shipping method config.  That will keep your free shipping deactivated in general until a shopping cart rule tells it otherwise.  I believe this is ONE of your problems. If you have 80 set there, it doesn't care about your rule, because the minimum 80 is already met.

Comment: Let me know if my above comment solves free shipping.  Then we'll move on to your table rate issue.

Comment: Also of course be sure no other rule is set to stop further rules processing and is of higher priority (lower number)

Comment: Ok, so, free shipping set to 10000. If I have $16 of product in my cart, there's no free shipping. If I add an Akubra hat in (i.e. the category I want to exclude), shipping becomes free. SO, the $80 target in my rule is being honoured, but not the category!

Comment: Does Akubra hat belong to any other categories?

Comment: If not, set second ALL back to ANY and try again.

Comment: I believe your points 1 and 3 should be solvable.  2 may or may not be easily solved depending on extension functionality.

Comment: Yes, Akubra is a subcategory of Hats.

Comment: GOT IT. Conditions: IF ALL THESE ARE TRUE:  If subtotal >= 80, AND Item IS NOT FOUND from Category 44 (i.e. just the target, not the parent cat) -=- ACTIONS, IF ALL conditions are TRUE, Category IS NOT targetcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21001/discussion-between-ladle3000-and-tmarsh1).

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED.

My target category was a sub cat.
i.e. Akubra (cat 44) was a sub-cat of Hats (cat 45).

I simply set it up like this.

Mage native Free shipping: threshold 10000
Rule:
Conditions

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
 Subtotal  equals or greater than  80  
 If an item is NOT FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
  Category  is  44
```

Actions

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
  Category  is not  44
```

Apply to shipping amount: no
Free shipping: for shipment with matching items
Stop further rules processing: no

Now,
a) if shipment is over $80, with no Akubra hats, shipping free
b) if shipping is under $80, use Aus Post (via API)
c) if Akubra in basket, use Aus Post, regardless of sub total

THANKS @ladel3000